# Как в sublime text удалить все после ":"

Tags: sublime-text

Как с помощью регулярного выражения удалить все после символа " : "?

Пример:

```
acdcrocks2002@yahoo.com:Corinth1
cyberkiller_11@yahoo.com:mariztela
```

Как из этого получить это:

```
acdcrocks2002@yahoo.com
cyberkiller_11@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

включить замену -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

включить regular expression -- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

поля:

Find: -- `:.*`

Replace: -- пусто

нажать кнопку: -- `Replace All`